# How to use native sqlite in ios' webview?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ipad, ios, webview

I just want to develop an ios app based on webview. The offline storage must be used. I know that html5 offline storage is supported by webview. But I just want to use a native sqlite file(not the one embedded in webkit) just like other native ios app. So could anyone please give me some clues?

Comment: What exactly do you want to store in the database?

Comment: I need clarification. Do you mean UIWebView?

Comment: Yes. It's UIWebView. Here is the use case. At first, a sqlite file will be included in the ios app. I just want to load it through javascript which loaded by UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

Are you implementing the database via javascript? If so check out this great free eBook on building iPhone apps. The chapter about Client-Side Database should give you a running start.

http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/ch05.html#ch05_id35933084

regards

Andrew

Comment: Not exactly, I'm not going to use the offline storage feature of HTML5. Actually, what I want is to call native method through javascript. I've found some frameworks such as "QuickConnectFamily" can do this. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

webSQL is available in UIWebViews.

However, if you're using Cordova the convention is to use the SQLite plugin. GIYF.

I personally like using web storage wrappers for this. Lawnchair.js and persistence.js were earlier wrapper solutions, but I like using Mozilla's [`localForage`](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/02/localforage-offline-storage-improved/) the most. It makes storing any kinda JS primitive/object/blob really easy.

`localForage` is just a wrapper over localStorage, webSQL, and SQLite. It has a really simple API and will choose the best web db for you based on what you wanted to store (was it serializable: localStorage. was it a [file Object] from an HTML input: webSQL). Your project can be a Cordova project or whatever. Don't matta. It'll work.